# LAR import failure on Liferay 6 with Weblogic 10.3

Tags: liferay, weblogic-10.x, noclassdeffounderror

I am trying to export pages as LAR from one community and trying to import this LAR into another community.
Bascially we wanted to export LAR from one environment and import into other environments.
During the import we are getting the following exception.
We are using the following configuration:
Liferay 6 Enterprise Edition installed on Weblogic 10.3
JDK 1.6
Unix Environment

Screen Error:
An error occurred while accessing the requested resource.

http://myserver.com:7003/en_GB/group/control_panel/manage?p_auth=Za3nNCBU&p_p_id=156&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=maximized&p_p_mode=view&doAsGroupId=12401&refererPlid=10165&_156_struts_action=%2Fgroup_pages%2Fimport_pages&_156_backURL=&_156_groupId=12401&_156_privateLayout=false

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/Element
        at org.jaxen.dom4j.DocumentNavigator.getChildAxisIterator(DocumentNavigator.java:231)
        at org.jaxen.expr.iter.IterableChildAxis.namedAccessIterator(IterableChildAxis.java:98)
        at org.jaxen.expr.DefaultNameStep.evaluate(DefaultNameStep.java:180)
        at org.jaxen.expr.DefaultLocationPath.evaluate(DefaultLocationPath.java:140)
        at org.jaxen.expr.DefaultXPathExpr.asList(DefaultXPathExpr.java:102)
        at org.jaxen.BaseXPath.selectNodesForContext(BaseXPath.java:674)
        at org.jaxen.BaseXPath.selectNodes(BaseXPath.java:213)
        at org.jaxen.BaseXPath.selectSingleNode(BaseXPath.java:234)
        at org.dom4j.xpath.DefaultXPath.selectSingleNode(DefaultXPath.java:159)
        at org.dom4j.tree.AbstractNode.selectSingleNode(AbstractNode.java:185)
        at com.liferay.portal.xml.NodeImpl.selectSingleNode(NodeImpl.java:211)
        at com.liferay.portal.lar.LayoutImporter.importLayout(LayoutImporter.java:818)
        at com.liferay.portal.lar.LayoutImporter.importLayouts(LayoutImporter.java:346)
        at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.LayoutLocalServiceImpl.importLayouts(LayoutLocalServiceImpl.java:706)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:115)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:86)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:60)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:60)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:60)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:93)
        at $Proxy96.importLayouts(Unknown Source)
        at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.LayoutServiceImpl.importLayouts(LayoutServiceImpl.java:300)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:115)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:86)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:60)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:60)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:60)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:93)
        at $Proxy97.importLayouts(Unknown Source)
        at com.liferay.portal.service.LayoutServiceUtil.importLayouts(LayoutServiceUtil.java:173)
        at com.liferay.portlet.communities.action.ImportPagesAction.processAction(ImportPagesAction.java:62)
        at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortletRequestProcessor.process(PortletRequestProcessor.java:174)
        at com.liferay.portlet.StrutsPortlet.processAction(StrutsPortlet.java:190)
        at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:70)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:48)
        at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:653)
        at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeAction(InvokerPortletImpl.java:689)
        at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.processAction(InvokerPortletImpl.java:361)
        at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.processPortletRequest(LayoutAction.java:840)
        at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.processLayout(LayoutAction.java:629)
        at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.execute(LayoutAction.java:240)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
        at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:170)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.callParentService(MainServlet.java:516)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:493)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:292)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:113)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:121)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:199)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:121)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.autologin.AutoLoginFilter.processFilter(AutoLoginFilter.java:240)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:75)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:500)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:248)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.FriendlyURLServlet.service(FriendlyURLServlet.java:136)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:292)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:121)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.strip.StripFilter.processFilter(StripFilter.java:301)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:121)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:199)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:113)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:113)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:121)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.etag.ETagFilter.processFilter(ETagFilter.java:55)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:121)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.autologin.AutoLoginFilter.processFilter(AutoLoginFilter.java:240)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:75)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:500)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:248)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.I18nServlet.service(I18nServlet.java:102)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:292)
       at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:121)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.sso.ntlm.NtlmPostFilter.processFilter(NtlmPostFilter.java:83)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:121)
        at com.liferay.portal.sharepoint.SharepointFilter.processFilter(SharepointFilter.java:80)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:121)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.virtualhost.VirtualHostFilter.processFilter(VirtualHostFilter.java:207)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:184)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:92)
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:738)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:164)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:92)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:164)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:92)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:75)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3592)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        ... 6 more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Jaxen` and `dom4j` are Liferay dependencies that reside in its `WEB-INF/lib` folder, while `jaxen` also exists in Weblogic system classpath. So when Liferay's `dom4j` looks for `jaxen`, the jar on the application server classpath is loaded first which in its turn tries to find `dom4j` and can't see portal application jars.

You can try to fix this situation for example by moving `dom4j.jar` from Liferay to Weblogic system classpath or by setting `prefer-web-inf-classes` option in the WEB-INF/weblogic.xml deployment descriptor of the Liferay application.

You can find additional info in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9002082/546117) question and [that](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/programming/classloading.html) document.