# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/DocumentHelper glassfish

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb, dom4j, classnotfound

I deploy a `ejb` module on `glassfish`, when some other modules invoke this module, it causes errors:

I have added `dom4j.1.6.1.jar` and `jaxen.1.1.6.jar` to the `glassfish` domain lib.

code below:

```
    LOGGER.info("no error in here1");
    document = DocumentHelper.createDocument();----->error here class not found
    LOGGER.info("no error in here2");
    root = initRootElement();
    LOGGER.info("no error in here3");
    request = createRequest(rootNAME);
    LOGGER.info("no error in here4");
```

error below:

```
[#|2014-09-02T20:30:57.256+0000|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.TieHandler|_ThreadID=1483;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|javax.ejb.EJ
BException
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.processSystemException(BaseContainer.java:5215)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:5113)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4901)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2045)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1994)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandler.java:213)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:79)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy293.isMatched(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor830.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie.dispatchToMethod(ReflectiveTie.java:144)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie._invoke(ReflectiveTie.java:174)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatchToServant(CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:528)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:199)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1624)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.SharedCDRClientRequestDispatcherImpl.marshalingComplete(SharedCDRClientRequestDispatcherImpl.java:
126)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaClientDelegateImpl.invoke(CorbaClientDelegateImpl.java:273)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.privateInvoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:200)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:152)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.codegen.CodegenStubBase.invoke(CodegenStubBase.java:227)
        at com.ericsson.ipinterface.__IIntelligentProvisioning_Remote_DynamicStub.isMatched(com/ericsson/ipinterface/__IIntelligentProvision
ing_Remote_DynamicStub.java)
        at com.ericsson.ipinterface._IIntelligentProvisioning_Wrapper.isMatched(com/ericsson/ipinterface/_IIntelligentProvisioning_Wrapper.j
ava)
        at com.ericsson.dve.inbound.cai3g12.CAI3G12Operation.getCreateResponse(CAI3G12Operation.java:1323)
        at com.ericsson.dve.inbound.cai3g12.CAI3GImpl.create(CAI3GImpl.java:216)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor827.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.InstanceResolver$1.invoke(InstanceResolver.java:250)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:149)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:94)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:961)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:910)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:873)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:775)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:386)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:640)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:263)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.invokeAsync(ServletAdapter.java:218)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doGet(WSServletDelegate.java:159)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doPost(WSServletDelegate.java:194)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet.doPost(WSServlet.java:80)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:688)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
**Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/DocumentHelper**
        at com.ericsson.ip.XSDGenerator.<init>(XSDGenerator.java:46)
        at com.ericsson.ip.IntelligentProvisioningImpl.generateSchema(IntelligentProvisioningImpl.java:219)
        at com.ericsson.ip.IntelligentProvisioningImpl.generateSchema(IntelligentProvisioningImpl.java:210)
        at com.ericsson.ip.IntelligentProvisioningImpl.isMatched(IntelligentProvisioningImpl.java:72)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor832.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5388)
        at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
        at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:162)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:144)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor831.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:370)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5360)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5348)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandler.java:206)
        ... 62 more
|#]
```

Comment: Related: [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/Document](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9002082/3357935)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the error. I add these jars with root. So glassfish modules have no authority to access these libs. When I changed ownership, it was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The `stacktrace` clearly states that other `org.dom4j` classes are present and being used. So it seems you have library version conflict.

`dom4j` and `jaxen` versions should be compatible with each other.

Compare their versions with those that work well in standalone mode.